# my first casper.js script being called from python

Tags: javascript, python, phantomjs, casperjs

pythonscript

```
import os
import subprocess
APP_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
CASPER = "C:\casperjs\bin\casperjs"
SCRIPT = os.path.join(APP_ROOT,'test.js')
params = CASPER + ' ' + SCRIPT
print subprocess.check_output(params, shell=True)
```

casper.js sample

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('http://casperjs.org/', function() {
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
});

casper.thenOpen('http://phantomjs.org', function() {
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
});

casper.run();
```

The Problem - The last line in my python script

**What I would like to know...**

- What is "print subprocess.check_output(params, shell=True)" doing, what is params, I assume shell means print to shell, aka command line. And why is it erroring?
- What is "APP_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(**file**))" ??? can you break it down into bits.

I got this from

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Acrx-AjCo8Q
```

Comment: You need to invoke it from a `.py` file. This will not work when running in the python shell because __file__ will not be defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something you could do:

Enter the following code into a file called `run_casper_sample.py`:

```
import os
import subprocess
APP_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
CASPER = "C:\casperjs\bin\casperjs"
SCRIPT = os.path.join(APP_ROOT,'test.js')
params = CASPER + ' ' + SCRIPT
output = subprocess.check_output(params, shell=True)
```

Then type on the command line the following:

```
python -i run_casper_sample.py
```

The `-i` option runs Python in an interactive shell.

Now inspect each thing you are interested in by doing things like:

```
>>> print(repr(APP_ROOT))
```

or just:

```
>>> APP_ROOT
```

You can also get some builtin help for various things for example:

```
>>> help(subprocess.check_output)
```

**NB:** the `>>>` are just markers to match the Python interactive shell.

Comment: keeps saying "NameError: name '__file__' is not defined"

Comment: Please paste the exact error in something like http://codepad.org/ or post a new question of the problem you're having. My answer above is sound and it does work.

Comment: hi the exact error is as above "NameError: name 'file' is not defined. This is line three in the code with APP_ROOT =blah.... Your answer unfortunately doesn't work for me. I am still continually prompted with Name, 'file' not defined.

Comment: @yoshiserry The reason I'm asking for an exact copy 'n paste is because what you describe is sadly inaccurate and wrong. The piece of code you pretend above and what I presented in my answer does not contain a reference to an object called ``file``. There is ``__file__`` but you don't seem to describe that here. Because of the disjoint I'm not actually sure how to help you :/

Comment: i copy n paste the code i said python n js in my question. i get...[joshua@JOSHUA-PC Documents]$ python open.py
  File "open.py", line 7
    print subprocess.check_output(params, shell=True)
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[joshua@JOSHUA-PC Documents]$

Comment: seems to have worked now thanks for your patience james.